# Firebase Crashlytics : Settings request failed - After migrate from fabric

Tags: android, firebase, crash, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

After I migrate to crashlytics from fabric, crash reports does not shown on Firebase console anymore.
I followed upgrade document for migration.

I tried force crash to test and i logged with `adb logcat -s FirebaseCrashlytics`,  I noticed an error with reading settings.
**FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings request failed.**

```
09-29 16:09:56.619   683   721 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Requesting settings from https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/gmp/1:657730209335:android:0f0486036fa5647e/settings
09-29 16:09:56.619   683   721 D FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings query params were: {instance=23c94567f3a0450c2c4276ef9c4f083d3e073ab9, build_version=714012888, display_version=7.14.0.128, source=1}
09-29 16:09:56.641   683   721 E FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings request failed.
```

Here is my settings.

```
{"settings_version":3,"cache_duration":86400,"features":{"collect_logged_exceptions":true,"collect_reports":true,"collect_analytics":false,"prompt_enabled":false,"push_enabled":false,"firebase_crashlytics_enabled":false},"app":{"status":"activated","update_required":false,"report_upload_variant":2,"native_report_upload_variant":2},"fabric":{"org_id":"5e00a1546bfe67fb08000062","bundle_id":"com.univera.android"}}
```

firebase_crashlytics_enabled" status **false** in settings.

Crashlytics enabled on console.

I m using version 17.2.1  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'` and i enabled CrashlyticsCollection `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);`

Why firebase_crashlytics_enabled" status false in my settings and whats wrong about settings request.

Does anyone see the raports on firebase console after migrate from fabric ?

Answer (score 4):

Your app must execute the following line to initialize Firebase at start-up:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getContext());
```

Also, you may want to set a user id so that crashes are tagged with the user id in the Firebase console:

```
FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserId("yourUserTag");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this) in OnCreate() method.

Comment: Should i remove and re add my firebase project on colsole ?

Comment: do you call FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this); ?

Comment: No. I call FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance() to report crashes.

Comment: Calling FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this) is needed to initialize the analytics SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android#add-sdk

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, having this error :

```
E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings request failed.
java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

This was a device specific issue. I have this error on a Xiaomi Mi A3, but when I launched the app on an emulator I had no error and the crashes appeared well in crashlytics.
There is no need to initialize Firebase in your code as matdev said.

Try running your app on a different device or emulator and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Check that you don't have an ad blocker blocking Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding firebase-settings.crashlytics.com to allow domain list in network-security-config

This may help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70858796/8499308